# exception handling when sequence exceeds max value

Tags: oracle

Hi very much new in oracle, how do you catch and reset back the sequence number when it reaches max value:

Here is the sequence script:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE idctr_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 99
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 10;
```

Then here's the code in which it tries to reset the value to 1 when the sequence reaches max. If the code works, I'll later convert it to function, but it fails.

```
declare
    seq_num number;
    exceed_maxvalue exception;
    pragma exception_init(exceed_maxvalue,-8004);
begin
    seq_num := idctr_seq.nextval;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(seq_num);
    exception
    when exceed_maxvalue then
        execute immediate 'sequence idctr_seq increment by -99 minvalue 0';
        execute immediate 'select idctr_seq.nextval from dual';
        execute immediate 'alter sequence idctr_seq increment by 1 minvalue 0';
end;
```

If I run the code till it reaches max value, it doesn't produce an error, but it doesn't also reset itself back to 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a use case for the [CYCLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) keyword; to quote

> indicate that the sequence continues to generate values after reaching either its maximum or minimum value. After an ascending sequence reaches its maximum value, it generates its minimum value. After a descending sequence reaches its minimum, it generates its maximum value.

Your object declaration should become:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE idctr_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 99
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 10
  CYCLE;
```

Here's a demonstration with a smaller sequence

```
SQL> create sequence test_seq start with 1 maxvalue 3 nocache cycle;

Sequence created.

SQL> select test_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

SQL> select test_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         2

SQL> select test_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         3

SQL> select test_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do doesn't make sense.

If you want your sequence to start again at 1 after it reaches 99, simply specify `CYCLE` when you create the sequence rather than the default of `NOCYCLE`

```
CREATE SEQUENCE idctr_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 99
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 10
  CYCLE;
```

Of course, there aren't a lot of cases where you really want a sequence to cycle-- normally, you'd declare the column to be large enough to handle however many values you could conceive of generating.  A sequence can generate an almost unfathomably large number of values before it reaches its default `maxvalue`.

Comment: Yep, that's why very much new in oracle, there's a CYCLE keyword that i didn't know it exists